# Android Inject Sensor Data

Tags: android, sensors, inject

We make a GameTV, which control by your Android phone and display on TV.
The game was installed on TV(android 8.0),and Client is installed on Android phone.
How to inject sensor data to TV?
The result we want is that any game can get the injectSensorData, such as TempleRun.
Can anyone give some advice or example?
The most important sensor is Accelerometer.

Comment: how you found how to do this I am struggling with this for a week

Comment: Put sensorservice in DATA_INJECTION mode and open a connection through which you can inject the fake sensor data. Take a look at this: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/refs/heads/android10-release/services/sensorservice/SensorService.cpp